# Booting Linux mint from USB - device not listed

Tags: linux, boot, usb, bios, linux-mint

I've recently gotten a new Linux box (HP Z4 G4 Workstation) and I'm trying to boot up Linux (Mint cinnamon 1.9) from a USB and I cannot get it to work. I used rufus portable (https://rufus.ie/) to configure the USB using the ISO file. When I boot the computer up, with the USB inserted, and head into the BIOS (F10) or the boot menu (F9) the bootable USB does not show up in the boot menu. I have moved all USB ports to boot up first in the boot sequence but the machine still boots up straight into what looks like windows. How can I get the machine to boot from my USB so I can load up Linux onto the computer? I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Other useful information:

HP Z4 G4 Workstation

processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2145 CPU @ 3.70GHz

Mem size: 32 GB ECC RDDR4

BIOS: P61 v01.86 10/10/2019

In Rufus I specified to use the GPT partition so it will work with the UEFI drivers. I have also tried disabling secure boot to get around the UEFI aspect but, that did not change the situation. I've also used balenaEtcher to create the bootable USB but that didn't solve the problem either.

Fastboot has been disabled

Comment: *"... or the boot menu (F9) the bootable USB does not show up in the boot menu"* -- Did you check every sublist, especially under "hard drive"?  I recall seeing the USB flash drive only listed in the "hard drive" list on one PC.

Comment: I've looked under every list or sub list I could. Hard drive doesn't come up but, 'boot from file does' couldn't see the usb in there either. I'm starting to think the usb just wasn't made bootable by Rufus or balenaEtcher

Comment: Although, the usb does come up on my personal laptop when I going into the bios and can change it to the top of the boot sequence so the usb must be bootable. Just not sure what's up with this HP computer

Comment: Download UEFI Shell from the following link. https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/UDK2018/ShellBinPkg/UefiShell/X64/Shell.efi  Rename it as bootx64.efi Create a FAT/FAT32 formatted pen drive. Create EFI folder at root of pen drive.Then inside it create Boot folder and place this bootx64.efi at /EFI/Boot on pen drive. Set boot mode UEFI and disable secure boot in firmware. Now try booting thru this pen drive into UEFI Shell and see if it works or not.